# restkit, how to access object in response without object mapping

Tags: swift, afnetworking, restkit, restkit-0.20

How can I access the original response json data without using object mapping. I have the followingresponse data. it contains a `nextSyncToken` which used to execute the query and a collection of items (within the `items` session).

I created a object mapping of the Item object which represent the contents in `items`. However, I also need the `nextSyncToken` field. How can I access it without object mapping. Since the syncToken has no relationship with object mapping. How can i deal with this.

```
{
  "kind": "calendar#events",
  "nextSyncToken": "COib8eSw78gCEOib8eSw78gCGAU=",
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "_74rk4cpg84o42b9k8or3gb9k74s34b9p8ks34b9m851kac9m64rk4ci36g",
      "created": "2010-04-16T11:09:31.000Z",
      "updated": "2010-04-16T11:10:27.487Z",
      "summary": "iCal test 1",
      "start": {
        "dateTime": "2010-03-16T21:00:00+08:00"
      },
      "end": {
        "dateTime": "2010-03-16T22:00:00+08:00"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "_752j2h1j6cq4cba68csjeb9k8p33eba1692k4ba284qj8ea688rj2chh6c",
      "status": "confirmed",
      "created": "2011-10-18T09:36:02.000Z",
      "updated": "2011-10-18T09:36:02.000Z",
      "summary": "New Event",
      "start": {
        "dateTime": "2011-10-18T03:45:00+08:00"
      },
      "end": {
        "dateTime": "2011-10-18T08:15:00+08:00"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My code of mapping:

```
    let eventMapping = RKEntityMapping(forEntityForName: "SGEvent", inManagedObjectStore: managedObjectStore)

    eventMapping.addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary([
        "id":               "identifier",
        "summary":          "summary",
        "created":          "createdAt",
        "updated":          "updatedAt",
        "location":         "location",
        "description":      "notes",
        "start.date":       "allDayStart",
        "end.date":         "allDayEnd"
        ])

    let startTimeMapping = RKAttributeMapping(fromKeyPath: "start.dateTime", toKeyPath: "startTime")
    startTimeMapping.valueTransformer = self.googleDateTransformer
    eventMapping.addPropertyMapping(startTimeMapping)

    let endTimeMapping = RKAttributeMapping(fromKeyPath: "end.dateTime", toKeyPath: "endTime")
    endTimeMapping.valueTransformer = self.googleDateTransformer
    eventMapping.addPropertyMapping(endTimeMapping)

    eventMapping.identificationAttributes = ["identifier"]

    let responseDescriptor = RKResponseDescriptor(mapping: eventMapping, method: .GET,
        pathPattern: "calendars/:calendarId/events", keyPath: "items",
        statusCodes: RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClass.Successful))

    objectManager.addResponseDescriptor(responseDescriptor)
```

My request operation:

```
  objectManager.getObjectsAtPath("calendars/\(identifier)/events",
        parameters: [self.ACCESS_TOKEN: accessToken], success: { (operation, results) -> Void in



            callback?(results: nil, error: nil)
        }) { (_, error) -> Void in
            print(error)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally you would add other response descriptors with appropriate mappings to deal with this issue.

When using `objectManager.getObjectsAtPath` you can get the raw data, assuming that you have some other response descriptor which will result in the success block being called, by navigating to the response data in the HTTP operation (which you can then unpack however you see fit):

```
operation.HTTPRequestOperation.responseData
```

(or use `responseString` instead of `responseData`).

Comment: can you give an example. I am pretty new with RestKit and iOS

Comment: That is all of the code to get the response data in the success block, then use it with a JSON serialiser or similar.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if let dict = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(operation.HTTPRequestOperation.responseData, options: .AllowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject],
      let nextSyncToken = dict?["nextSyncToken"] as? String{
    print(nextSyncToken)//get the nextSyncToken
}
```